# Javascript / jQuery time event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I want to know if it is possible to make an event listener that will respond once a certain time has expired. Can I make objects register with a main 'thread' that counts and when I go over that object, it's time is notified and it can do it's action?

I essentially want to have an object that counts the seconds/milliseconds and then other objects can use it to check times once a second and if they are over then that can be called?

I have a scrolling gallery that shuffles every 3 seconds, but wanted it to pause and have multiple other scrolling actions that invalidate the time so thought a notification center might be a better way than with `setInterval()`;

EDIT: I want something that ticks in the background and independent listeners that can wait until after their time and then do something. These independant listeners need to be able to be reset individually too so I can say: gallery item 3 reset timer etc

Comment: It's not at all clear what you want beyond the facilities offered by "setTimeout()" and "setInterval()".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into incorporating:
http://weblog.bocoup.com/publishsubscribe-with-jquery-custom-events

Comment: That does look like something similar to what I was after.. I will look into it :D

Comment: That seems spot on. The events are what I used :-)

Comment: cool, ironically, I haven't got a chance to play with it too much yet myself :(

Answer (score 2):

There's a jQuery plugin I built that might be what you're looking for.  Your code would look like this.

```
var timer = $.timer(function() {
    // gallery code here
});    
timer.set({ time : 5000, autostart : true });
```

You can use play(), pause(), reset(), toggle(), etc...

http://jchavannes.com/jquery-timer

Comment: This is pretty handy. I have managed to come up with a work around for what I needed but will defiantly keep yours bookmarked for the future :D